# Can't apply gradients on tf.Variable

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to learn a similarity matrix(M) between two image embeddings, A single instance of training is a pair of images - (anchor, positive). So ideally the model will return 0 distance for embeddings of similar images.

The problem is, when i declare the distance matrix(M) as a tf.Variable, it returns an error
on this line
`self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))`

> TypeError: 'Variable' object is not iterable.

I think I should use a tensorflow datatype for M, that is iterable

Please tell me how I can fix this issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
# metric learning model
class MetricLearningModel:

    def __init__(self, lr):
        self.optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr)
        self.lr = lr
        self.loss_object = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
        self.trainable_variables = tf.Variable(
            (tf.ones((2048, 2048), dtype=tf.float32)),
            trainable=True
        )

    def similarity_function(self, anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings):
        M = self.trainable_variables
        X_i = anchor_embeddings
        X_j = positive_embeddings
        similarity_value = tf.matmul(X_j, M, name='Tensor')
        similarity_value = tf.matmul(similarity_value, tf.transpose(X_i), name='Tensor')
        # distance(x,y) = sqrt( (x-y)@M@(x-y).T )
        return similarity_value

    def train_step(self, anchor, positive):
        anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings = anchor, positive
        # Calculate gradients
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Calculate similarity between anchors and positives.
            similarities = self.similarity_function(anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings)

            y_pred = similarities
            y_true = tf.zeros(1)
            print(y_true, y_pred)
            loss_value = self.loss_object(
                y_pred=y_true,
                y_true=y_pred,
            )
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, self.trainable_variables)
        # Apply gradients via optimizer
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))


metric_model = MetricLearningModel(lr=1e-3)
anchor, positive = tf.ones((1, 2048), dtype=tf.float32), tf.ones((1, 2048), dtype=tf.float32)
metric_model.train_step(anchor, positive)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function expects iterable objects, like for example a list or a tuple.

In your calls to `tape.gradient`, or `optimizer.apply_gradients`, you can put your Variable in a list to solve the issue :

```
with tf.GradienTape() as tape:
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [self.trainable_variables])
# Apply gradients via optimizer
self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [self.trainable_variables]))
```

`tape.gradient` respects the shape of the `sources` object passed to compute the gradients of, so if you feed it with a list, you will get a list out of it. It is stated in [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient):

> Returns
> a list or nested structure of Tensors (or IndexedSlices, or None), one for each element in sources. Returned structure is the same as the structure of sources.